# CSS, Stretching vertically div until it reach the height of its parent

Tags: css, html, height, stretch

Wrapped in a `pageWrapper` container, I have 3 divs in a column. First (header) and last (navWrapper) have fixed heights. I need the middle one (`contentWrapper`) to stretch in height until the parent div pageWrapper reaches the maximum height (*according to the browser's viewport*).

I draw the *schema* of this problem.
[image]

Here is a **fiddle of my current solution.** 
http://jsfiddle.net/xp6tG/

and here the code

CSS and HTML

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  background-color: #E3E3E3;
}

#pageWrapper{
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
}

header{ 
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

#contentWrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

#navWrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="pageWrapper">
  <header>
    Header
  </header>
  <div id="contentWrapper">
    Content
  </div>
  <div id="navWrapper">
    Nav
  </div>
</div>
```

It is almost working, but it results in too high height, which causes that a vertical scrollbar appears.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it.

Apply the following **CSS**:

```css
html, body{ height: 100%; margin: 0;}
body{ background-color: #e3e3e3;}

#pagewrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 100%;
}
header{ 
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
}
#contentwrapper{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 0;
    background: blue;
}
#navwrapper{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    background: green;
}
```

Since you specified heights for the `header` and `#navwrapper` block elements,
you can use absolute positioning with respect to the parent `#pagewrapper` block 
to set the bottom and top offsets for `#contentwrapper` and the bottom offset for 
`#navwrapper`.

If you see a scroll bar, you may need to set `margin: 0` for either the `html` and/or `body` tags.

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/yUs6r/

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding this script in your  section after your CSS is called. It will find the heights of your head/foot elements and make the height in the center div fill the screen. This is good because if you decide to make your header/footer elements heights dynamic this script will still work.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        var totalHeight = $('#pageWrapper').height();
        totalHeight -= $('header').height();
        totalHeight -= $('#navWrapper').height();

        // Remove an extra 20px for good measure
        totalHeight -= 10;

        $('#contentWrapper').css('height', 'auto');
        $('#contentWrapper').css('min-height', totalHeight);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I also made the height element set min-height so if your content is larger than the set height the div will expand as normal